# Configuring MySql server in my C project

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, embedded-sql

I have a problem where I need to include a MYSQL-server into my C Project (VS 2008).
The program uses a built-in library from other software which tries to collect and stores some part of data.

I have searched the internet for `Embedded SQL` and I end up finding only how to program SQL in C.
Can anyone Please answer my question : How do I connect my MySQL-server to my code (Visual Studio 2008). The server and the code are on the same system. There is no internet connection or server type connection.

Comment: Look for info about 'libmysql.dll'. There's an API for talking to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks .. but the problem is .. I just forgot to mention ..
I am **NOOB** to database programming and just not clear about all the details. Can u please explain a little elaborately.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html